# sprintf format for uint_fast16_t?

Tags: c++, printf

I am having problem with format for uint_fast16_t

```
    uint_fast16_t runningOrderNo;

    std::string ATNativeConnector::_GetNextClOrdId()
{

    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm* tim = localtime(&t);

    std::stringstream sstr;
    char temp[10];
    sprintf(temp, "%02d%02d%02d%03u", tim->tm_hour, tim->tm_min, tim->tm_sec, ++runningOrderNo);
    sstr << temp; //<< std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << tim->tm_hour << tim->tm_min <<  tim->tm_sec << ++runningOrderNo;
    runningOrderNo %= 999;

    //LOG4CXX_DEBUG(logger,"Generated " << sstr.str() << " second:" << tim->tm_sec << " order id");
    return sstr.str();
}
```

I get an warning like this.

ATNativeConnector.cpp:6156:95: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 6 has type ‘uint_fast16_t {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]

I tried different formats from [this](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__inttypes.html) page, will be thank full if someone will help me.

Comment: Just dump `sprintf` and use `std::stringstream` for the formatting.

Comment: I'm with @CaptainObvlious! `sprintf` is oldschool :-)

Comment: Naa, I can't have some reason for why I am doing it in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way would be to use the `PRIuFAST16` macro from the page you linked:

```
sprintf(temp, "%02d%02d%02d%03" PRIuFAST16, ..., ++runningOrderNo);
```

The macro expands to a string, which is then joined by the preprocessor with adjacent string literals. This way the slightly strange looking `"%02d%02d%02d%03" PRIuFAST16` ends up as one string literal containing the correct format specifier.

Comment: Include a space between the macro and the quote to avoid issues with user defined string literal lexing rules. I know some compilers work around UDL issues here by recognizing allowed strings, but it's still good practice to use a space.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `PRIuFAST16` macro, as [sth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24329056/827263) suggests, is the most correct solution.

An alternative (one that I find more readable) is to convert the argument to a known type. For example:

```
uintfast_16_t n = 42;
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)n);
```

You have to be careful to select a type that's wide enough to hold the value being converted; it's theoretically possible, but vanishingly unlikely, that `uintfast_16_t` could be wider than `unsigned long`. (In this case `unsigned int` is almost certainly good enough.)

If you're paranoid, use `uintmax_t`:

```
printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)n);
```

The advantage of this approach is that you and any readers of the code don't have to remember (or look up) the rather terse macro names.

The disadvantage is the risk of picking a type that's not wide enough and the (very minor) inefficiency of converting the operand to a wider type before printing it.

Of course using `std::stringstream` rather than `sprintf` avoids the issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

As others correctly pointed out you have to use the `PRIuFAST16` macro with `printf`. But since you asking about C++ (based on the tag), I'd recommend avoiding `printf` altogether and using a type-safe alternative such as [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt):

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

auto s = fmt::format("{:02}{:02}{:02}{:03}",
                     tim->tm_hour, tim->tm_min, tim->tm_sec, ++runningOrderNo);
```

Note that you can omit all type specifiers (`d`, `u`, `PRIuFAST16`) because `fmt::format` is based on variadic templates and preserves the type information.

A formatting facility based on this library is proposed for standardization in C++20: [P0645](http://wg21.link/p0645).

Moreover, you can use `strftime`-like formatting for the date portion of your string to improve readability even further:

```
#include <fmt/time.h>

auto s = fmt::format("{:%H%M%S}{:03}", *tim, ++runningOrderNo);
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt}.